# How to print PDF, image and HTML documents from android device to a printer on wifi?

Tags: android, html, pdf, printing

I need to implement document printing functionality in my android app.
I was able to print image file using the android printing framework code mentioned below :

```
private void doPhotoPrint(Bitmap bigbitmap) 
{
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(MainActivity.this);
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bigbitmap);
}
```

I went through the existing threads discussing the same question, but none of them help much.

The issue I am facing is with other document types like PDF and HLML.
It would be helpful if someone could give some insight on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this code

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";



        PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;

                try {
                    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "fact_sheet.pdf");                 
                    input = assetManager.open("fact_sheet.pdf");                        
                    output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                    //Catch exception
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Catch exception
                } finally {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                    return;
                }

                // int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);

                PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();

                callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
            }
        };
      printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);  
    }
```